# Confusion over lmer and p-values: how do p-values from memisc package compare to the MCMC ones?

Tags: r, mixed-model, p-value, markov-chain-montecarlo, lme4-nlme

I was under the impression that the function `lmer()` in the `lme4` package didn't produce p-values (see [`lmer`, p-values and all that](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-May/094765.html)).

I've been using MCMC generated p values instead as per this question: [Significant effect in `lme4` mixed model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/33687) and this question: [Can't find p-values in the output from `lmer()` in the `lm4` package in `R`](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38188/cant-find-p-values-in-the-output-from-lmer-in-the-lm4-package-in-r).

Recently I tried a package called [memisc](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/memisc/index.html) and its `getSummary.mer()` to get the fixed effects of my model into a csv file. As if by magic, a column called `p` appears which matches my MCMC p-values extremely closely (and doesn't suffer the processing time that comes with using `pvals.fnc()`).

I've tentatively had a look at the code in `getSummary.mer` and have spotted the line that generates the p-value:

`p <- (1 - pnorm(abs(smry@coefs[, 3]))) * 2`

Does this mean p values can be generated directly from `lmer`'s output rather than running `pvals.fnc`? I realise this will no doubt start the 'p-value fetishism' debate but I'm interested to know. I've not heard `memisc` mentioned before when it comes to `lmer`.

**To be more succinct: What is the benefit (if any) of using MCMC p-values over those generated by `getSummary.mer()`?**

Comment: I am the original author of the `getSummary.mer` function. The reported $p$-values should only be used as a quick check. If I recall, I actually only included the $p$-values to make it work within the framework provided by `memisc`. But this should really be provided with an appropriate warning to the user, and I will contact the package maintainer to see about getting this added. My advice is to follow that provided by Doug Bates: MCMC is the safe bet (assuming others don't have better options).

Comment: @JasonMorgan This looks to me to be a pretty reasonable answer to the question.

Comment: @JasonMorgan I agree with what you say but currently `mcmcsamp()` is not available because of a number of issues (One can check the `Status of mcmcsamp` section in glmm.wikidot.com/faq for more details). I feel that at the moment time, probably (parametric?) bootstrapping is a viable -and not too hard to implement- alternative; the `bootMer()` functiom can be of service.

Comment: @Glen_b Should I just copy-paste my comment as an answer?

Comment: @JasonMorgan I think a copy-paste would be fine, since to my eyes your valuable comment does actually answer the question. (However, if you feel you can expand even a little on your explanation of why the p-values should really only be used as a quick check rather than as p-values, or when they may be more likely to be poor approximations, or why MCMC is a safe bet, so much the better.)

Comment: @JasonMorgan Thanks for your comment, happy to accept it as an answer if you paste it as such. One thing I did note was that pvals.fnc does appear to generate identical figures to getSummary.mer() in its Pr(>|t|) output. I've seen in another tutorial (the location escapes me) that these values should be compared to the MCMC p values as a sense check, just as you mentioned.

Comment: One other technical/terminological note to the OP. The p-values obtained using the method in `memisc` are the p-values from treating the observed test statistics as Wald statistics (treating the *t* as a Wald *z* in this case). Such a test relies on the "large sample" assumption and so is more and more trustworthy as your sample sizes grow larger. The MCMC-based value, to my knowledge, does not rely on such an assumption. So anyway, reading a little about Wald tests and alternatives to them could help to shed further light on your question.

Comment: @JakeWestfall Is there any document demonstrating that the MCMC-based method has satisfactory frequentist properties ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent It is a good question and unfortunately I don't know the answer. I don't know too much about MCMC to be honest. Maybe someone else who knows more about the usage here could chime in, or maybe you could even expand your query into a whole separate question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am the original author of the `getSummary.mer` function. The reported $p$-values should only be used as a quick check. If I recall, I actually only included the $p$-values to make it work within the framework provided by `memisc`. But this should really be provided with an appropriate warning to the user, and I will contact the package maintainer to see about getting this added. My advice is to follow that provided by Doug Bates: MCMC is the safe bet (assuming others don't have better options).