# How to obtain p-values when using glmer - mixed model logistic regression GLMER?

Tags: logistic, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, p-value

I have performed a mixed model logistic regression using glmer and used afex::mixed to obtain the correct pvalues.

```
mixed(model_9, data = ReversalTaskData, method = "PB", test_intercept = T, 
      family = "binomial")
```

but I receive this message

Formula (the first argument) converted to formula.
Numerical variables NOT centered on 0: Stimulation, Block
If in interactions, interpretation of lower order (e.g., main) effects difficult.

I was wondering if lmertest can be used as well obtain p-values in case of logistic (thus, non-linear) mixed model regression. do you have any other suggestion, otherwise?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to obtain the p-value (check significance) of an effect in a lme4 mixed model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22988/how-to-obtain-the-p-value-check-significance-of-an-effect-in-a-lme4-mixed-mode). Also related: [1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/38189/176202), [2](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-May/094765.html), [3](http://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#testing-hypotheses)

Comment: I checked that posts but they consider lmer and not glmer.